# aws-sdk-cpp simplest Makefile for POC

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I'd like to use C++ sdk on my instance using GNU GCC. I am following this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html

and would like to download an object from s3. I will be using GNU GCC compiler. 
I plan on using the code as given on this page: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/cpp/example_code/s3/get_object.cpp
    1. In this case, do I still need a Makefile to deal with the dependencies below?
    2. Could you please show me the simplest Makefile to use as a proof of concept?

```
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.h>
#include <fstream>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a pain to use plain Makefile to deal with dependencies and paths. I recommend you to use CMake. You can follow instructions here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/developer-experience-of-the-aws-sdk-for-c-now-simplified-by-cmake/

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. That is what I ended up doing.